# Problems overriding foundation.css

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, zurb-foundation

I'm adding my own classes to index.html in another stylesheet while using foundation's css, but some of my styles are not showing up, eg: class="topNav" in the html:

```
<header class="row topNav">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <h3>Logo Name</h3>
    </div>
</header>
```

My styles in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font.css" />
```

What I want to achieve in the css (change the color of header):

.topNav { background-color: #000; } /*this is not working*/

There's nothing wrong with the path or file structure. Also, I'm also using foundation 4.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting us to use telepathy to be able to determine what issue you're having? Have you used the browser's dev tools to see what css *is* being applied? Is it a specificity issue? Is there a typo in the class name?

Comment: @zzzzBov Sorry..I didn't think I needed to be too detailed since I don't have any other explanations except that my main.css isn't overriding the foundation.css. I haven't done much with the code at all...so perhaps I'm missing something...

Comment: It's just that you haven't provided any code that someone could use to actually debug the issue. Have you tried making a [reduced test case in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Have you examined the dev tools to be certain that the files are loading correctly? [*What have you tried to do to debug this issue for yourself?*](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I took a look chrome's dev tool and main.css for .topNav doesn't appear. I also tried rearranging the <link /> order. I also tried taking out foundation.css, and main.css works 100%, but when I add it back in, it doesn't work. I'm a bit new to jsfiddle, but I will give it a try now.

Comment: @zzzzBov I worked it out in jsfiddle. I'll start using jsfiddle to help debug from now on. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *need* to just override it for now, include an [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules) rule:

```
.topNav {
background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

But you should post the relevant CSS so you can come up with a more specific selector as its pretty much bad practice to use `!important` especially if you abuse it .. its better to figure out whats causing the conflict

Answer (score 4):

To over-ride foundation css put your custom css script under the foundation css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone out there who may be having the same problem - I was too, until I figured out that if you download Foundation 4 as the default version, you can override app.css just fine.  But it you download a customized version of Foundation 4, a lot of the special components such as buttons will not override foundation.css using app.css.  It should say this on the Foundation documention somewhere - it would save everyone a lot of time!